# unable to find activate.bat to activate conda environment via batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda, environment

I used to have a batch file in a previous computer, scheduled via task scheduler, that activated the conda environment called "eng" and ran a python script with the packages installed in that environment. The bat file looked like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Conda Activate for MTD ENT Daily pull
@CALL "C:\Users\tom\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" eng
ECHO
python C:\Users\tom\OneDrive\Files\Python\myfiles\mycode.py
ECHO End
```

I had to migrate to a different computer and installed anaconda, but now, I cannot find that activate.bat file in Scripts folder. The only one I can find is this one in an nt folder (environment is also called eng) within the scripts folder:

```
C:\Users\alopez006\.conda\envs\eng\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\activate.bat
```

but that does not seem to be the right one because it is telling me that cannot find the module pandas. I have read that this is an installation error from anaconda and that I need to uninstall and reinstall again, but I wasn't sure this is true or not for the scenario I have or perhaps I did find the correct `activate.bat` file and I am missing something else.

Is it perhaps somewhere else? if not, can it be fixed without uninstalling anaconda? I can uninstall and reinstall if I have to but if I can avoid that it would be ideal since we share this computer with other people. any thoughts? Thanks

Anaconda version I have is 2022.10

**Edit**:
I created a second environment and it is also missing the activate.bat file. The first environment was created in anaconda prompt using

```
conda create --eng python=3.6.13
```

the second environment I created via anaconda navigator, using the create environment button.

Comment: The folks who wrote the venv code decided that you shouldn't be able to move or copy virtual environments, and hardcoded a lot of things that result in trying to do so anyway breaking everything. So: you'll need to first make a _new_ one in the new project dir you want to work in, then copy your files over.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes, I created a new environment, but it is also missing the activate.bat file.

Comment: Then please [edit] your post to [include that detail](/help/how-to-ask), and explain _how_ you created a new environment, because that matters, of course.

Comment: Start by changing `@CALL call` to `@CALL`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I edited the post and added more details to it.

Comment: @Compo I removed the second call in there. still the issue persists.

Comment: [There is no `--eng` flag for `conda create`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html) so I'm surprised that even did anything.